# how to show mouse hover for 10 second on navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

code:

```
<style>
   .subnav-show {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('.nav li').hover(
        function () {
            $('ul', this).addClass('subnav-show').delay(2000).queue(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('subnav-show').dequeue();
        });               
    });
});
</script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="n-bar"></span>
                <span class="n-bar"></span>
                <span class="n-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
                    <a href="#" id="home" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >home</a>              
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu" id="div2">
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <p>menu1</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <p>menu2</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <p>menu3</p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <p>menu4</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>               
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code I have creating a large menu navigation bar when I mouse over on menu then it show large drop down bar and when I remove mouse from menu then suddenly large drop down menu hide. Now, My question is how to show large menu bar for 10 second when mouse over on menu and If I remove mouse from menu then it show large menu for 10 sec after then it hide ? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Why the PHP tag?

Comment: Does the `:hover` rule applied to the navigation bar, to display the dropdown menu, apply to the dropdown menu as well? If not, this dropdown menu will naturally hide as soon as you move away from it. But if the `:hover` rule is applied to the dropdown menu as well, when you hover off the navigation bar, and onto the dropdown menu, it will remain visible. Suggestion: include your CSS

Comment: I am using jquery @JustBaron but it can't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://www.bootply.com/64081

```
jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn();
}, function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: but this doesn't help, he's asking for a way to keep the hover active when he puts the cursor on a certain thing, and viceversa. This is very different from the answer he expects.

Comment: You are right! Edit my answer, this example will solve the problem

Comment: if you're gonna use jquery, use it as it's supposed, with the `$(".ul.nav li.dropdown")` stuff and all that. this way you don't mix 2 tools and he might get interested in learning more jquery

Comment: If it so important - ok) but in bootply this solution works well even with jQuery) Thanks.

Comment: No it's not really important, just to make it more jqueryish

Comment: Remove your code and add the above jQuery code between <script></script> tags and add the following html https://www.bootply.com/NvdezJVVt3